# ¿Cómo grabar sonidos del altavoz y el micrófono simultáneamente con Python en Windows?

Tags: python, windows, audio

Intenté grabar el sonido desde el desktop con pyaudio, pero solo pude obtener el sonido del micrófono, pero también quería el altavoz. También descargué el portaudio, pero no estoy seguro de si puedo obtener el sonido del altavoz y el sonido del micrófono simultáneamente. Este es el código que obtiene el sonido del micrófono:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp/tmp.wav"

class recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False
        self.process = None
        self.filename = "ScreenCapture.mpg"
    def record(self,filename):
        try:
            if self.process.is_alive():
                self.going = False
        except AttributeError:
                print("test")
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename
    def _record(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                        channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        #print("* recording")

        frames = []

        self.going = True

        while self.going:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)

       # print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False
```

Estoy usando Windows y también puedo usar otra biblioteca, no solo PyAudio. Solo necesito hacer que esto funcione.
¿Qué debo hacer? ¡Gracias!

**Código Actualizado:**

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp/tmp.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


class recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False
        self.process = None
        self.filename = "ScreenCapture.mpg"
    def record(self,filename):
        try:
            if self.process.is_alive():
                self.going = False
        except AttributeError:
                print("test")
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename
    def _record(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        # stream usando as_loopback para obtener sonido del sistema operativo
        stream = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=2,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=2,
            as_loopback=True)
        ## transmitir usando el dispositivo de entrada de mi micrófono
        stream2 = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=1,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=1)
        # as_loopback=False)
        #print("* recording")

        frames = []
        frames2= []

        self.going = True

        while self.going:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)
            frames2.append(data2)
        # frames = datos de sonido as_loopback (altavoces)
        frames = b''.join(frames);

        # frames2 = datos de sonido del micrófono
        frames2 = b''.join(frames2);

        # decodificación de datos del altavoz
        Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')

        # decodificar los datos del micrófono

        Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

        # convertir los datos del altavoz en un vector Numpy (facilitando la vida al recoger canales de audio)
        Sdecoded = np.array(Sdecoded, dtype='int16')
        # obtener los datos en el lado derecho
        direito = Sdecoded[1::2]

        # obteniendo los datos en el lado izquierdo
        esquerdo = Sdecoded[::2]

        # mezclar todo a mono = agregar lado derecho + lado izquierdo + datos decodificados de micrófono que ya son mono
        mix = (direito + esquerdo + Mdecoded)

        # asegurando que ningún valor va más allá de los límites de short int
        signal = np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

        # codificar los datos nuevamente
        encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh" % (len(signal)), *list(signal))

       # print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        stream2.stop_stream()
        stream2.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(encodecoded)
        wf.close()


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False
```

¿Por qué no funciona?
Hice el código muy limpio y comenté cada parte para que entiendas lo que está sucediendo. Hice un for loop al principio para que Pyaudio me mostrara cuáles son las interfaces que tengo en mi sistema operativo.

```
0 Mapeador de som da Microsoft - Input
1 Microfone (Realtek(R) Audio)
2 Mixagem estéreo (Realtek(R) Aud
3 Mapeador de som da Microsoft - Output
4 Alto-falantes (Realtek(R) Audio
5 Alto-falantes (Realtek(R) Audio)
6 Microfone (Realtek(R) Audio)
7 Mixagem estéreo (Realtek(R) Audio)
8 Speakers 1 (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
9 Speakers 2 (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
10 Alto-falante (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
11 Microfone (Realtek HD Audio Mic input)
12 Mixagem estéreo (Realtek HD Audio Stereo input)
```

Pude grabar el micrófono y el sonido de audio del sistema con este script, pero quería que funcionara dentro del proyecto:

```
    import pyaudio
    import wave
    import numpy as np


    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = 2
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp.wav"


    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


    for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
        print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


   #stream usando as_loopback para obtener sonido del sistema operativo
    stream = p.open(
        format = FORMAT,
        channels = 2,
        rate = RATE,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
        input_device_index=0,
        as_loopback=True)
    ## transmitir usando el dispositivo de entrada de mi micrófono
    stream2 = p.open(
        format = FORMAT,
        channels = 1,
        rate = RATE,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
        input_device_index=1)
        #as_loopback=False)


    frames = []
    frames2 = []


    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
        frames2.append(data2)

    #frames = as_loopback datos de sonido (altavoces)
    frames= b''.join(frames);
    # frames2 = datos de sonido del micrófono
    frames2= b''.join(frames2);
    #decoding datos del altavoz
    Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')
    # decodificar los datos del micrófono
    Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

    #convertir los datos del altavoz en un vector Numpy (facilitando la vida al recoger canales de audio)
    Sdecoded= np.array(Sdecoded, dtype='int16') 

    # obtener los datos en el lado derecho
    direito=Sdecoded[1::2]

    # obtener los datos en el lado izquierdo
    esquerdo=Sdecoded[::2]

    #mezclando todo a mono = agregar lado derecho + lado izquierdo + datos decodificados de micrófono que ya son mono
    mix=(direito+esquerdo+Mdecoded)

    #asegurando que ningún valor vaya más allá de los límites de short int
    signal=np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

    #codificar los datos nuevamente
    encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh"%(len(signal)), *list(signal))


    #detener todas las transmisiones y finalizar pyaudio
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    stream2.stop_stream()
    stream2.close()
    p.terminate()


    #Grabar audio mezclado en mono
    wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(1)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes((encodecoded))
    wf.close()
```

Comment: Obtener sonido del altavoz?? o reproducir sonido por el altavoz? Lo primero no es posible, el microfono si es un dispositivo de entrada, el altavoz lo es de salida

Comment: Pero no puedo obtener el sonido del sistema?

Comment: No se , si eso es posible, o si funciona asi. El sistema y aplicaciones reproducen sonido, y es el sistema o aplicacion el que envia sonido al dispositivo que este configurado, monitor , altavoces, auriculares, etc. Puedes reproducir cualquier sonido por el altavoz , pero si lo que quieres es que todos los sonidos del sistema y otras aplicaciones salgan por un dispositivo, tendras que establecer el que desees como predeterminado

Comment: mi idea sería crear una grabadora de pantalla que obtenga el sonido del sistema (salida del altavoz) y el micrófono

Comment: por ejemplo camtasia

Comment: yo quise decir audio buffer antes de que salga al altavoz

Comment: Era lo que imaginaba, para que sistema seria windows o linux?

Comment: Sistema Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyAudio no tiene soporte para capturar el sonido que llega al output de windows, pero hay un fork que suple esa carencia:

https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio

Simplemente debes añadir el parámetro `as_loopback = True`

```
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                    as_loopback = True)
```

Comment: Hola César. Después de agregar este parámetro todavía no puedo escuchar la salida de Windows. ¿Sabes lo que podría ser?Instalé este fork de acuerdo con la configuración descrita en el enlace y no pude escucharla. También quería saber si es posible escuchar el micrófono y el output de windows al mismo tiempo.

Comment: En PyAudio deberías especificar el dispositivo de entrada que quieres utilizar con input_device_index porque por defecto te va a devolver la entrada de audio asignada por defecto por Windows. Revisa el código de ejemplo de la documentación de PyAudio-Portaudio (es muy autoexplicativo) disponible en https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio/blob/master/example/echo_python3.py

Comment: Otra opción sería abrir dos streams diferentes en caso de que sigas sin poder capturar todos los canales en el mismo stream, uno para el micrófono y otro para el loopback de la salida de audio

Comment: Hola César. ¿Puedes ver mi código actualizado? No funciona por alguna razón, pero creo que casi estoy solucionando el problema.