# ¿Cómo grabar el sonido de los altavoces con sounddevice en Python?

Tags: python

nececito capturar el sonido del equipo que se emite por los altavoces, como videos, juegos u otros. Estoy usando la librería sounddevice, si bien logro grabar del micrófono, no así de los altavoces.
intenté cambiando el dispositivo de entrada asignando el de salida (altavoces) con la instrucción "sounddevice.default.device", sinembargo me arroja un error porque presisamente se trata del dispositivo de salida.
Estuve viendo que con "Stream()" es posible usar puertos al mismo tiempo, pero no logro dar con la solución. Dejo el código.

```py
import sounddevice
import wavio

def grabar():
    sounddevice.default.device = 2 #el número 2 es el ID del dispositivo output que me gustaría grabar, pero arroja error (asumo que no debe acerse de este modo))
    grabacion = sounddevice.rec((5*44100), samplerate= 44100, chanels= 2)
    sounddevice.wait()
    wavio.write('audio.wav', grabacion, 44100, sampwidth=2)
```

Comment: y cual es el código que tienes?

Comment: Acabo de poner el código en el mensaje principal

Comment: al vez e pueda ayudar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/320755/183782)